# Is 'was' an auxiliary verb in 'All I could do was watch from outside'?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

I found this sentence,

> All I could do was watch from outside.

Looks like this sentence contains 2 verbs 'was' and 'watch' but 'was' is actually working as an auxiliary verb, right?

Comment: _To be_ is often used as an auxiliary verb, but it isn't one in this case. _All I could do_ (the only action I could take) **was** _[to] watch from outside._

Comment: @Muukii You are right. With one very minor exception, "be" is **always** an auxiliary verb.

Comment: Would you explain a bit more about 'be is always an auxiliary verb'? bit confused because be is also a verb according to the dictionary for instance. https://www.dictionary.com/browse/be

Comment: @Muukii Auxiliary verbs are a sub-type of verb.

Comment: yeah I know but ‘be’ could be also a verb, right?

Comment: for instance, ‘This is a pen.’ this case ‘is’ runs as verb from my understanding

Comment: @Muukii Yes, "is" is a verb, an auxiliary verb to be precise.

Comment: I see. that's the news for me.

Comment: @Muukii See my answer for the reason why.

Answer (score 4):

> All I could do was (to) watch from outside.

This construction is fine; *was* is a *copula* (or *linking verb*); the infinitive phrase *watch from outside* is the subject complement.

The infinitive marker *to*, which I inserted, is optional.  According to *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language*,

> The bare infinitival is restricted to cases where the subject NP contains *do* in a relative clause[.]

**Edit to Answer Further Queries**

The verb *was* in

> All I could do *was* (to) watch from outside.

is not an auxiliary verb; it is a linking verb.

> Linking verbs, also known as “copular verbs,” are a type of *main verb* [emphasis added]

As for auxiliary verbs (or helper verbs),

> A helper verb will always come before the main verb in a sentence.

Hence for *was* to be an auxiliary verb,  *watch* would need to be a main verb:

> I *was watching* from ...

> The scene *was watched* from ...

That's not the case in OP's example, where *watch* is an *infinitive*.

Collins Dictionary explains further, that *the verb **be** is also used as a [main verb. It is commonly found joining a subject to its complement.](https://grammar.collinsdictionary.com/easy-learning/how-do-you-use-the-verb-be-in-english).*

Comment: Yes. You might also mention that with just one exception "be" is always an auxiliary verb.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I just want to know the link to `According to The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language` if you have it.

Comment: @Muukii, I quoted that from somewhere.  I don't  think that part is accessible free of charge.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question.The OP seems to know the sentence is grammatical. They're asking if *was* is an auxiliary verb in the example (they asked it on EL&U]

Comment: @BillJ, As I understand this analysis of OP's sentence, "watch" is not the main verb. This makes it appear odd to call "was" an auxiliary verb. Do you class "is" as an auxiliary verb in "the sky is blue"?

Comment: Thanks, @Araucaria - Not here any more.  I have explained further in my answer.

Comment: @Peter Yes, I do. The verb "be" is always an auxiliary even if it is the only verb in the clause.

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore I'm sorry, but you have got it wrong. The copula verb "be" is an auxiliary verb. See CGEL p113 2.5.7. It says that copula "be" has all the properties A-H, i.e. those of an auxiliary verb, CGEL p108 [48].

Comment: The question was if "was" in the text is an auxiliary, not if the sentence was correct use.

Comment: @BadZen, I did state clearly both in my original answer (6 Mar) right at the front '*was* is a *copula* (or *linking verb*)', and again 16 hours ago 'The verb *was* in "All I could do *was* (to) watch from outside." is ***not an auxiliary*** verb; it is a linking verb.'

Comment: Thanks, @BillJ.  I can't access CGEL and hence can't verify this.  I guess we'll just respectfully agree to disagree :).

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore I've attached a link to a summary of CGEL. If you scroll down to 6.4 [27] 111 you'll see that copular "be" is analysed as an auxiliary. [link](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html) Note that it says _"be" is the only verb, but it still behaves as an auxiliary_.

Comment: @SeowjoohengSingapore I've attached a link to a summary of CGEL. If you scroll down to 6.4 [27] iii, you'll see that copular "be" is analysed as an auxiliary, [link](http://www.lel.ed.ac.uk/grammar/overview.html)  Note that it says of their example that _"be" is the only verb, but it still behaves as an auxiliary_.

Comment: Did you look at the link I gave you?

Comment: Thanks very much, @BillJ. Yes, I did.  "In [iii] ***be*** is the only verb, but it still ***behaves*** as an auxiliary.  I'm not sure whether ***it behaves*** means ***it is***.

Comment: Yes, it means that it behaves like an auxiliary verb, and thus it is one. Importantly, it has the NICE properties. There are several references to this in CGEL and its excellent baby brother _A Students Introduction to English Grammar__ (SIEG for short).

Comment: I've added to my answer an extract from SIEG, which makes it clear that "be" is an auxiliary verb. I hope it helps.

Comment: @BillJ - Read the excerpt in your answer, with the paragraph that precedes it, in light of its indended pedancy.   The author is says that "be" is to be catagorized as "an auxiliary verb" in English, as if we were making a list of such verbs and found it necessary to decide which are and are not, categorically.  Contrast with OP's actual question, which asked if it was "actually working as an auxiliary verb".  Look at the authors converse example of static lexical verbs which are "analyzed as" aspective in some sentences, etc.  'Be' "is an auxiliary verb" because it sometimes acts as one.

Comment: To wit:  if OPs question were "is 'to be' categorized as an auxilliary verb in English", you and the author and everyone else here would enthusiatically agree.  However:  "in this sentence, is 'to be' functioning as an auxilliary, adding aspect to an otherwise complete lexical verb clause?"  No, it is not.  (Some verbs usually can provide aspect when they stand alone, for some reason he calls these 'quasi-modal' or invents another category for these uses in CGEL - here he just effectively says "let's say the verbs are auxiliary and distinguish between use, instead".)

Comment: (Finally, most grammars that aren't CGEL / Huddleston define lexicals positively as a category, saying "if it can stand on its own in this clause, it's lexical".  CGEL definitely does some stuff "thinking different" - for example Huddleston does not recognize a future tense in English...  you would probably not want to tell language learners this, and cite the corresponding analysis, right?)

Answer (score 2):

> *All I could do was* [*watch from outside*].

Here, "was" is an auxiliary verb, not a lexical one.

The bracketed sequence is predicative complement of "was", meaning that the latter can only be a form of copular "be".

Copular "be" is an auxiliary verb in that in has all the relevant properties of auxiliary verbs.

In fact, with just one exception, "be" is always an auxiliary verb, even if it is the only verb in the clause.

Note that the label 'main verb' is irrelevant here. "Was" is just as much a main verb as "watch" is.

[image]

Comment: If "was" is a main verb, how can it be an auxiliary verb as well?

Also:  "be" in "Be kind!" is auxiliary according to your rule.

Comment: @BadZen Was it you who downvoted my answer?

Comment: Yes, because it is incorrect, and I explained why it is incorrect.   Arguing about "who downvoted me" and "vote wars" make the answers here low-quality and everyone's experience bad, so "Was it you?" is 100% unhelpful.

Comment: @BadZen Who are you to say my answer is incorrect? You are not a linguist or a grammarian, yet you seek to contradict the answers of those who are. And it's your comments that are low quality. You need to study scholarly English grammar, and learn the facts. Further, the "be" in "Be kind" is indeed a lexical verb. It's the one exception that I tacitly referred to in my answer.

Comment: [Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/be#be__15), [Lingua Press](https://linguapress.com/grammar/to-be.htm#:~:text=The%20verb%20to%20be%20as,to%20its%20qualities%20or%20characteristics.)  and [Learn Laugh and Speak](https://learnlaughspeak.com/verb-to-be/?irclickid=V4L2%3APQ61xyPRPUxoCTql0XVUkHyXOSRSzR53w0&irgwc=1) says *In English grammar, the verb to be is unique in that it can function both as a main verb and as an auxiliary verb. **As a main verb, it is used to express a state of being, such as “I am happy.**”* Are all these resources and sites so wrong?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It can be argued but it's very, very hard to maintain. It's verging on a "The Earth is flat" kind of claim. Many EFL books maintain this description, but it has basically disappeared in linguistics. It causes havoc for learners. For example, consider the following questions: How do you make yes/no questions in English? Where do you put adverbs of frequency (e.g. *always*)  in English? How do you make a tag question in English? How do you give emphatic positive stress in English? How do you make *wh*-questions in English? How do you make a negative declarative clause ... (1/2)

Comment: @Mari-LouA What verbs contract with the word *not* in English? When do we need the auxiliary verb *do* in English? See! Absolute havoc! The idea's a hundred years out of date. Dictionaries and EFL publications  are largely still wedded to eighteenth/nineteenth century ideas about grammar. (2/2)

Comment: Also, consider these pairs  which compare "be" as the only verb with its use in marking the progressive aspect: "He is acting strangely" ~ "He is insane". / "Is he acting strangely?" ~ "Is he insane"?  /  "He isn't acting strangely" ~ "He isn't insane". In each of those pairs "be" is behaving exactly the same.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. I think one of the problems is that many people use the terms 'main verb and 'auxiliary verb', as though they were in contrast. But the contrast is actually lexical verb vs auxiliary verb. Every clause, main or subordinate has a so-called 'main verb' (overt or understood), and this verb is either lexical or auxiliary.  In other words, it's better not to talk of main vs auxiliary, but of lexical vs auxiliary.

Comment: @BillJ Does CGEL use "main verb"?

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Only (as far as I know) on p104, [38] where it makes the same point that I did in my last comment. Some years ago, I had a very interesting email discussion about auxiliary verbs with RDH. Would you like a copy?

Comment: @BillJ Yes, please!!!

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. Yes, I am convinced you're both right but the three sites I linked to, and one of them is Cambridge Dictionary i.e. CUP the same publisher as CGEL, appear to disagree and they weren't written in the late 19th century nor even the mid-twentieth century. I mean the authors must be hovering between  40 and 60 years old (if not younger!).

Comment: @Mari-LouA Well, the dictionary is easier to explain: [Why dictionaries are hundreds of years out of date!](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6609/calling-out-a-comment-dictionaries-are-bad-sources-for-determining-words-part/6635#6635). As for the EFL books, I can't put my finder on exactly why, although I have a vague theory.

Comment: @BillJ  "You are not a linguist".   Assume less, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

In this post I've swapped the word *I* in the Original Poster's example for the word *Bertha*. This is just to make it easier to compare with other examples.

---

1. Bertha was swimming.
2. Bertha was praised.
3. Bertha was in the tree.
4. Bertha was hot.
5. Bertha was Brenda's sister..
6. All Bertha could do was watch from outside.

In sentence (1), the verb *was* is a necessary part of the present continuous construction. It is taking the verb *swimming* as a catenative complement. *Was* is clearly an auxiliary verb here.

In (2) the verb *was* is a necessary part of a passive construction. It's taking the verb *praised* as a catenative complement. Again it's clearly an auxiliary in this example.

In (3) the verb *was* links the subject with the locative complement *in the tree*. Although there's no second verb after *was*, it is still an auxiliary verb here. Appearing with another verb is not a necessary condition for being an auxiliary verb. Auxiliary verbs:

- invert with subjects to make yes/no questions
- contract with the negative word not
- can be used without the rest of the verb phrase (when what is missing can be understood)

The word *was* in (3) can do all of these things:

7. **Was** Bertha in the tree?
8. Bertha **wasn't** in the tree.
9. Was she in the tree? Yes, she **was** [in the tree].

*Was* is clearly an auxiliary verb here.

In (4) the verb *was* takes an adjective (phrase) as a predicative complement—the word *hot*. There is no following verb after *was*, but this verb still shows all of the auxiliary properties we've just talked about. For example, it can contract with *not* to give *Bertha **wasn't** hot*. This is an ᴀsᴄʀɪᴘᴛɪᴠᴇ use of the verb *BE*, where its complement, the adjective *hot*, tells us about some property or quality of the subject.

In (5), *was* is still an auxiliary because we can get sentences like *Was Bertha Brenda's sister?* and *Bertha wasn't Brenda's sister*. It is taking a noun phrase as a complement. This is not an ascriptive use of the verb *BE*, but a sᴘᴇᴄɪғʏɪɴɢ use. It tells us the identity of the subject (Bertha), or that the two phrases, the Subject and the predicative complement both refer to the same thing or person.

In (6) the verb *was* is followed by the verb *watch*. We might think that these are forming part of a tense/aspect/voice construction as in examples (1) and (2). And it would be easy to make the mistake of thinking that *watch from the outside* is the catenative complement of *was* here. But it isn't. Example (6) is not like examples (1) and (2), it is like example (5)! Here we see a specifying use of the verb *BE*. The phrase *watch from the outside* is the *predicative* complement of the verb *BE*, and tells us what *all Bertha could do* refers to.

We can see, then, why the Original Poster might ask whether *was* is an auxiliary in (6). It looks a bit like a typical auxiliary with a catenative complement, like the verb *was* in examples (1) and (2). However, it isn't. The verb phrase after *was* is a predicative complement, just like the noun phrase after *was* in example (5). And just like the *was* in (5), the *was* in (6) is an auxiliary verb. In fact, the word *was* is ***always*** an auxiliary verb!

Comment: +1 A bit long but, yeah, fine.

Comment: All I could do was watch from outside. = Watch from the outside was all I could do. Was=copular.

Comment: CGEL covers this construction on p1255 7.3

Comment: @BillJ Thanks, I've looked of *all*-clefts in CGEL before and couldn't find them.

Answer (score 0):

- All I could do was watch from the outside.
- Watch from the outside was all I could do.

**was** here is a copular verb aka linking verb:

This is an inverse copular construction:

> In linguistics, inverse copular constructions, named after Moro
> (1997), are a type of inversion in English where canonical SCP word
> order (subject-copula-predicative expression, e.g. Fred is the
> plumber) is reversed in a sense, so that one appears to have the order
> PCS instead (predicative expression-copula-subject, e.g. The plumber
> is Fred). The verb in these constructions is always the copula be (am,
> are, is, was, were). *Inverse copular constructions are intriguing
> because they render the distinction between subject and predicative
> expression difficult to maintain*. The confusion has led to focused
> study of these constructions,[1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_copular_constructions#:%7E:text=In%20the%20inverse%20copular%20constructions,languages%20such%20as%20German%2C%20e.g.&text=%27The%20pictures%20are%20a%20problem.) and their impact on the theory of
> grammar may be great since they appear to challenge the initial binary
> division of the sentence (S) into a subject noun phrase (NP) and a
> predicate verb phrase (VP) (S → NP VP), this division being at the
> core of all phrase structure grammars (as opposed to dependency
> grammars, which do not acknowledge the binary division).
>
> The defining trait of the inverse copular constructions is that two
> counts of inversion appear to have occurred: the normal subject has
> inverted to a post-verb position, and the predicative nominal has
> inverted to the pre-verb position. The verb is a finite form of the
> copula 'be' (am, are, is, was, were). This type of inversion is
> generally NOT possible with other verbs.
>
> Subject-verb agreement Inverse copular constructions where the
> inverted predicative expression is a noun phrase are noteworthy in
> part because subject-verb agreement can (at least in English) be
> established with the pre-verb predicative NP as opposed to with the
> post-verb subject NP, e.g.
>
> a. The pictures are a problem. - Canonical word order, standard
> subject-verb agreement b. A problem is/??are the pictures. - Inverse
> copular construction, subject-verb agreement reversed in a sense a.
> Those kids are an annoyance. - Canonical word order, standard
> subject-verb agreement b. An annoyance is/??are those kids. - Inverse
> copular construction, subject-verb agreement reversed in a sense In
> the inverse copular constructions, the copula agrees with the singular
> predicative expression to its left as opposed to with the plural
> subject to its right. This phenomenon seems to be limited to English
> (and possibly French); it does not occur in related languages such as
> German, e.g.

[inverse copular construction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_copular_constructions#:%7E:text=In%20the%20inverse%20copular%20constructions,languages%20such%20as%20German%2C%20e.g.&text=%27The%20pictures%20are%20a%20problem.)

Comment: Why is it your first example and not the second which you regard as an inverted copula (aka a subject-dependent inversion construction)?

Comment: Are you really asking that??

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Comment: I put the first one first because it is the question, and the second shows it can be inverted. Pretty obvious and better than saying "was" is a "helping verb". It meets none of your criteria for one.

Comment: But it's not called an invertable copula, it's called an inverted copula. So you need a way of establishing which one is the uninverted form.

Comment: Omg, **I didn't say it's called an invertable copula**, though it is in fact invertable. That's you saying it.

Comment: Sorry, should have said "It's not **defined** as an invertable ... but inverted". Here's the bit from the text: "inverse copular constructions, named after Moro (1997), **are a type of inversion** in English **where canonical SCP word order ... is reversed**

Comment: (Not my downvote, by the way). So in the text a clear distinction is made between "Fed is the plumber" (normal) and "The plumber is Fred" (Inverted).

Comment: the second sentence should start from Watching or To watch, doesn't it?

Comment: @Muukii No, *I gave you the two*. Here's another: Play football is all he does. All he does is play football. No ing and no to play.

Answer (score -2):

> All I could do was watch from outside.

"was" is used here exactly as in the following sentence:

> My pocket was empty.

In both of these cases, "was" is a main verb.

Compare this with:

> I was watching from the outside.

In this case, there is a second verb "watching" with the same subject. "was" is a helper that expresses a mood or tense, "watching" is the main verb.

In each of the first two examples, there is no second verb that shares a subject with "was".

Comment: Please explain your downvote if you believe the answer is incorrect.  Retributive downvoting is disallowed and unhelpful.

Comment: Could you please cite a reference which supports your idea. I have always heard (and known) that *be* is an auxiliary, and can/could are modal verbs  "*All she **could do was** watch from outside*." and "*All **they could do** ***were (?)*** *watch from outside*.